# WSO2 2.1 APIM distributed set up

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi I have distributed set up for WSO2 2.1 APIM in aws. I have published sample Pizza Shack API but its not getting updated at gateway manager node. Can someone help me why api artifact is not getting updated on gateway manager node ?

Machine 1 : Has WSO2 publisher(portoffset 0) and store(portoffset 1) running.
Machine 2 : Has gateway manager(portoffset 0), gateway worker(portoffset 1), traffic manager(portoffset 2) and key manager(portoffset 3) running.

Also when I open and edit sample pizza shack API and go to managed tab I see missing Endpoint and Endpoint Type fields as shown below :
[image]

Ideally it should like below :
[image]

[root@ip-10-0-1-76 ec2-user]# tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1500 port 9443

I just tried to see if is there any traffic coming from publisher machine to gateway manager and saw below output. Looks like gateway manager is receiving some traffic on port 9443 but don't know what's happening after that.
[image]

Comment: does the publisher has correct gateway URL defined in the api-manager.xml? (the Environments tag)

Comment: @gusto2 yes its there <ServerURL>https://${xxx.gatewayManager.host}:${xxx.gatewayManager.mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL> and port here is 9443 since gateway manager has portoffset 0.